# How to access OS level time-format setting ion React Native

Tags: android, react-native

I need to format my time stamp based on OS level time-format setting, 12-hour or 24-hours. How can react-native directly access the OS-level setting? 
Current research brings up native bridge. Is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: You may checkout this package [`react-native-device-info`](https://github.com/rebeccahughes/react-native-device-info), and use [`is24Hour`](https://github.com/rebeccahughes/react-native-device-info#is24hour) prop

Comment: That's the same thing. It' using native code to determine. I dont want a bridge to native, but looking for a purely React Native solution